# \mathcal in equation

Tags: equations

any suggestions to produce this equation using Mathcal

My code :

```
 \[
\mathsf{S_j}=\mathcal{X} \mathsf{IG}(\upsilon_{1},T_{1})+(1-\mathcal{X}) 
 \mathsf{IG}(\upsilon (\mathsf{S_{j-1}}), T(\tilde{\mathsf {V}}))
 \]
```

what i wanted as output :
[image]

Comment: Please, show the code of your trials, so that other users don't have to do everything for you.

Comment: Could you precise what you mean? There are no calligraphic letters in this equation.

Comment: I thought "x" is produced using \mathcal  !

Comment: With this piece of code, it's better, but it's not enough, your code must be compilable and minimal. [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Answer (score 4):

This symbol that looks a bit like a calligraphic "x" is in fact a kappa, which can be obtained with the command `\varkappa`. The output of the following example seems to match the picture you posted in the question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
S_j = \varkappa IG(v_1, T_1) + (1 - \varkappa) IG \bigl( v(S_{j-1}), T(\bar{V}) \bigr)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]